# Отредактировать элемент массива

Tags: php, массивы, циклы, foreach

Есть массив ввида:

```
Array
(
    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 40335
            [1] => 40336
            [2] => 218
            [3] => 217
            [4] => 40337
            [5] => 38301
            [6] => 39051
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => 8782
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => 11112
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [0] => 11123
        )
```

Нужно сделать, чтобы каждый элемент имел ввид: 40335.jpg, кусок кода:

```
$getDb = R::getAssoc('SELECT id, producer, parent, title, keyword, art, price, good_chars, balance, img_name , description FROM ' . $data);
$imageId=[];
    foreach($getDb as $key=>$arrDb){
        $imgList= $arrDb['img_name'];
        $imageId[$key] = explode(',', $imgList) ;
    }

    print_r($imageId)
```

Никак не получается сделать, чтобы сохранились ключи у массива

Comment: Вы приводите в примере один массив, но при этом в цикле оперируете какими-то `img_name` и `explode` по запятой. Откуда? Почему? И зачем? Как это связано?

Comment: А вообще, раз это данные из БД, то сразу в запросе можно и сконкатенировать данные как нужно и не париться

Comment: Да, извиняюсь, забыл. Img_name тянется из таблицы:"$getDb = R::getAssoc('SELECT `id`, `producer`, `parent`, `title`, `keyword`, `art`, `price`, 
        `good_chars`, `balance`, `img_name` , `description` FROM ' . $data);" , в таблице номера идут списком, через запятую у некоторых записей в таблице несколько img_name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$imageId = [
    'a' => [11, 12, 13],
    'b' => [21, 22],
];
// array_walk_recursive($imageId, function(&$item){$item .= '.jpg';});
$imageId = array_map(function($list){
    return array_map(function($id){
        return $id.'.jpg';
    }, $list);
}, $imageId);

var_export($imageId);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$imageId=[];

foreach($getDb as $key=>$arrDb){        
    $imageId[$key] = array_map(function($el) { 
        return $el . '.jpg';
    }, explode(",", $arrDb['img_name']));
}
```